# How to disable access from the same domain iframe to parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

We give user possibility to create html page. It is stored on our server. Moreover user can send this page to other our user. For showing of page a iframe is used. For security reason it is needed to disable access from this iframe to parent window. As both pages are from the same domain then access is possible. It would be possible to use sandbox but youtube does not work in sandbox iframe if allow-same-origin and allow-scripts are not specified. But in this case iframe has access to parent. Also it is not possible to use different domains as for this a separate SSL sertificate is needed.
What can be made under these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

if you think about it you will see that Displaying the same page in an iframe would result in an infinit loop of displaying the same page. I suggest you find another work-around for your problem. If you face any problems you are free to come back and ask for real help if you have a real problem.

sincerely
a truthful friend

Comment: There is page A which is created by user and there is separate page B which is used for displaying page A in iframe. Therefore there cannot be infinite loop.

Comment: Then please give us some code. So we can help you finding your issue.

Comment: I cannot give code as I do not know how to make it. Main question: how to disable access iframe to parent page from the same domain without using sandbox?